# Chat popup using Django + Jquery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, chat

I am developing a  chat system. I want a new popup window to appear whenever a client try to contact another client. so how can I create a popup window to be opened on a certain event like when client receive a message.

I am using Django, Jquery.

thanks.

Comment: I think you should post a little bit of code, if you want an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the accepted answer on this post:

[How does Facebook chat avoid continuous polling of the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663882/how-does-facebook-chat-avoid-continuous-polling-of-the-server/2663903#2663903)

I think the [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) technique mentioned here would be best for your situation and could help you to avoid constant AJAX polling.

You could set up a Django view that worked as a client to a chat server, constantly listening, then it could close its connection and send the response to the browser (the hanging AJAX request) whenever a new event is received from the chat server.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Its helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using jQuery UI Chatbox Plugin. It provides a widget and is easy to integrate.
http://www.cs.illinois.edu/homes/wenpu1/chatbox.html